# How to use a RegEx in Perl's LibXML findnodes

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I have the following in an XML Document:

```
<ul class="toggle-control toggle-retain-state">
```

I'm using XML::LibXML to parse the entire document, and I need to take action when it finds the above item.  The code I have inherited was:

```
my ($toggle_container) = $xRoot->findnodes('.//*[@id = "toggle-control"]');
```

It seems that the first problem with that code is that the attribute is class, not id.  So I changed that to class, but it still fails to find it.  I'm guessing it is because of the class being "toggle-control toggle-retain-state", but What I'm really looking for is a match anytime it sees just the toggle-control in the class attribute.  How do I change the findnodes call to make that happen?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgoten to upvote -- now done. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//ul[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' toggle-control ')]
```

**Remark**: Always try to avoid the `//` abbreviation when the structure of the XML document is known. Using the `//` abbreviation may lead to significant inefficiency.

Comment: I think I understand, but I'm getting syntax errors.  Can you include my original Perl Line of code and incorporate your solution?

Comment: @Schenz: I don't know Perl, this is pure XPath. I have verified that the XPath expression in my answer is syntactically and semantically corect. Please, read the appropriate documentation for non-XPath related issues.

Comment: looks like I just had to escape the @ symbol :)

Comment: Where should I go for good XPath Documentation on the web so I can figure these out myself?

Comment: Look in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: If you use a single-quoted string, like `q{//ul[... @whatever ...]}`, then you won't have to escape the `@`.

Comment: I like adding spaces before and after the attribute value to be able to use contains instead of a more complex regex on the bare value.

Comment: How behaves the xpath in the accepted answer differently than this xpath '//ul[contains(@class, "toggle-control")]' ?

Comment: @sid_com: `//ul[contains(@class, "toggle-control")]` will select many possibly unwanted `ul` elements such as: `<ul class="Mytoggle-control toggle-retain-state">`, while the XPath expression in this answer does not select such elements.

Comment: Aha, I think I've understood it too.